# Traduzindo plugin wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Estou tentando traduzir uma frase no Plugin UT Portfolio, fui na pasta do arquivo e tem somente um arquivo .txt avisando que a tradução deve ser feita pleo plugin codestyling localization, porém já ao abrir ele apresenta este erro de permissão, como proceder?

Minha hospedagem é umbler.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Esse plugin funciona reescrevendo os arquivos `.po` e `.mo` que contém as traduções. Muitos servidores não permitem escrever arquivos pelo CMS pelos riscos de segurança.

Você pode alterar esses arquivos diretamente usando um editor como o [PoEdit](https://poedit.net/).

Procure na pasta do plugin uma pasta "languages" ou "lang" e os arquivos `.po` ou `.pot`. Baixe para o seu computador, abra nesse programa e altere as traduções que quiser, depois salve para gerar novos arquivos e suba para a mesma pasta no servidor.

Comment: Possui uma pasta chamada lang dentro do plugin, porém não contem nenhum arquivo .po ou .pot, apenas um readme.txt mandando baixar o plugin de tradução que citei no tópico =/

Efetuei o download do programa e tentei traduzir o .po original do wordpress, imaginei que talvez eles teriam alterado ou algo assim.. porém estava 100% traduzido...

Comment: Não me lembor bem o nome do comando, mas o PoEdit tem uma função de ler o codigo do plugin e criar o arquivo `.pot`, ai a partir dele você poderia traduzir.